# How to use Docker to deploy WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, windows, docker

I know from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/containers-modernizing-traditional-net-apps-with-docker#where-docker-fits-in-net-solutions) that I cannot use Docker to **run** WPF applications. However I have the use case that I would essentially like to create containers that can easily be shared to then **deploy** my WPF application onto another Windows computer or VM.

The purpose of this is to be able to quickly deploy new test versions of the WPF application without having to provide testers access to the full code base and expect them to rebuild or have to develop and maintain a full installer at an early stage of development.

The application is MVVM based WPF with Prism, with a target framework of .Net Core 3.1 and a SQLite database.

The bolded text below implies this is possible:

> Docker is for server applications—Web sites, APIs, messaging solutions and other components that run in the background. You can’t run desktop apps in Docker because there’s no UI integration between the Docker platform and the Windows host. That rules out running Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) apps in containers (**although you could use Docker to package and distribute those desktop apps**), but Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), .NET console apps and all flavors of ASP.NET are great candidates.

However I have struggled to find clear documentation for how to do this. Is this possible and if so where can I find the appropriate documentation? If I have misunderstood this please let me know, I am also unsure if this question belongs here or on the Software Engineering stack and am happy to move it if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Github builds in docker. You can just file copy of unzip a window app assuming you have .net framework on a machine. You don't get faster than that.

Comment: Why are you targeting net core 3.1?

Comment: We are targeting net core 3.1 as some of the libraries we are using for some specific actions in our code are not supported in newer versions.